# Are all known non-BCS superconductors doped Mott-insulators?

Tags: superconductivity

The question is similar to [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/621356), where I've read with interest [Mike Stone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/80687/mike-stone)'s comment. A yes or no-with-counterexample answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Undoped [Strontium ruthenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strontium_ruthenate) superconducts while breaking time-reversal symmetry.